# Error building Static Library with OpenCV and Xcode on C++

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, static-libraries

I'm trying to build a DLL library for Unity3D (in 32-bit) but first of all I want to make a `.a` static library to make a C++ Wrapper for C#.

Well, this is what I've done.

1. I've built OpenCV unchecking **BUILD_SHARED_LIBS** in order to get the **STATIC LIBS**, with architecture **i386**.
2. I've made my static library code and built it, Linking the static libraries that I needed (I really import them all because I'm having errors and I want to know if it's an error lib-based):

[image]

(included from `/lib/` and `/3rdparty/lib/`)

3. I'm linking my library and header in a new project (Command Line Tool) in order to test my new static library, but my errors are:

[image]

([pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/Pspwq7gu))

Well, I have no idea what's wrong.

**This is my settings on the static library:**

[image]

**This is my settings on my test Command Line Tool (for testing my library)**

[image]

Does anyone have idea about this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

---

**EDIT:** tried to manipulate the static libraries for 64 bits as well but nothing happened.

Comment: I assume you want to use opencv on osx only. On the test command line tool project - can u try with 1) `build active architecture only: yes`. 2) Also please give result of `lipo -info libzliba.a` on command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was removing several paths on the Library paths since it was messing up some libraries.

Comment: "several paths on the Library paths" it is not clear. Can you give more details?